# How do I get stream of file contents where each two bytes are swapped?

Tags: java, endianness

In Linux I can read file content and display it as hex value. To do so I use the following command:

```
$ hexdump inputFile
```

This command for a file of mine gives:

```
0000000 5747 8114
```

Note that first `0000000` is offset. The data is `5747 8114`.
To read first two bytes and have them swapped the following code could be used:

```
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(inputFile))
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
is.read(bytes, 0, 2);
int result = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt(0);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(result)); // prints 5747
```

However, this seems too complicated and error prone.
Note that I wrote a code that reads a file into byte[] and then swapps bytes, i.e.

> A, B, C, D

becomes

> B, A, D, C

However, this is not an option for big files.
**So, how do I get stream of file contents where each two bytes are swapped the way I described above?**

Comment: As an example, one can wrap file content in a Stream of bytes and then the stream can be customly reduced with swapping logic. What do you think about it?

Comment: @MikhailKopylov Seems interesting, please provide some code.

Comment: Is this binary file with all byte pairs swapped or file with little endian encoded 16bit values?

Comment: Note that the order the individual bytes are shown in, does not necessarily reflect the order they are found in the file.

Comment: @PiotrPraszmo How do I check this? Note, that the file is not produced by me.